# Show $\int_{0}^{1}(\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt)^2 dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(1-x^2)(g(x))^2 dx$ for any $g(x)$ continuous

Tags: integral-inequality

Prove (or disprove) that
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_0^x g(t)\ dt\right)^2dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (1-x^2)(g(x))^2 dx$$
for any $g(x)$ continuous on $[0,1]$.

I have verified the cases of $g(x)$ being monomials like $x^k (k\in \mathbb{N})$ and found the equality holds iff $k=0$, namely, $g(x)\equiv 1$.

Comment: **Hint :** The inequality holds using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality first, and then Fubini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt\right)^{2}dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{0\leq t\leq x}g(t)dt\right)^{2}dx\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{0\leq t\leq x}^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}(\chi_{0\leq t\leq x}g(t))^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}\right)^{2}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x}dt\right)\left(\int_{0}^{x}(g(t))^{2}dt\right)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}x\left(\int_{0}^{x}(g(t))^{2}dt\right)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}x(g(t))^{2}dtdx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{t}^{1}x(g(t))^{2}dxdt\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}(g(t))^{2}\int_{t}^{1}xdxdt\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}(g(t))^{2}\dfrac{1}{2}(1-t^{2})dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^{2})(g(x))^{2}dx.
\end{align*}